# Token authentication for Web API renewal

Tags: c#, oauth, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

I’m writing a web api that will be called from a background service to fetch some data. After some research I decided to use a Json web token to achieve that but I’m still a bit confused regarding when a new token should be requested.

Let’s say I start up my service, I request a token, the token expires after 15 minutes, then after 20 minutes I make an api call with the expired token. I will get an unauthorized error or something.

**My question is: How will the client know when to request a new token? Should it request a new one before every api call? Seems like I’m missing something. Maybe I should make the token permanent and store it in the database?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is slightly application specific, but the OAuth specification has a mechanism for "refresh tokens", which can be used to grant new "access tokens" (the token typically included on each API request), without having to send the user to the UI authentication process to have them re-authenticate.  So, once you request an access token, you will receive a refresh token and an access token.  This methodology allows access tokens to be used for much shorter time frames.

This can also be done without refresh tokens, but in those cases the access token timeout would likely be longer, and then you would request that the user re-authenticate through the usual OAuth UI process.  Note that even when you do have refresh tokens, the refresh token can also be set to expire, in which would then require a user re-authentication through UI again.

In some API's you just make the API request as usual, and if you get a response that is defined by the API to be one that indicates the access token has expired, you can then issue an API call to refresh the token (or fully request a new one if that is expired, or you the API doesn't have refresh tokens), and then make the original API call again with the new access token.

The API can also have a response that includes the timeout or expiration date/time of the access token as well.  Then, the client can avoid sending the initial API call first, and simply send the refresh token call first.

In implementing your API, you could likely use any of these methodologies.

Here's some general discussion on the OAuth spec website, to provide more depth:
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

And also, here's an example from the Twitter API regarding response codes showing one of the access token expiration techniques (see the "Error Codes" section, under error code 89, which implies the token has expired and you need to get a new one):

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes

Comment: Do you know how it works on mobile apps? You only need to login once to access the APIs.

Comment: This would work the same way as in the browser.  But for a mobile app, you can either use refresh tokens (which allow the access token to be refreshed when it expires as the refresh token has a much longer expiration, typically), and possibly even have no refresh token expiration (or no access token expiration), especially when the app is made by the same company as the API.

Answer (score 1):

Since your client is  background service , you can use the [Oauth2 Client Credential Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) . Your background service can request an access token using only its client credentials   when the client is requesting access to the protected resources under its control.

With this flow , you does't need to care much about the token expires , if client sends an expired token to web api , web api validate the token and create token expires response to your service , your service check the status code/response , directly send a new token request to web api to get new access token , there is no need to use `refresh token` which uses in other flows .

Comment: But that means that I will have to check the response for each API call that I make and check if there was a 'token expired' error and then request a new token and remake the API call. Seems like a lot of repeated code.

Comment: You can check the token expire on client side when making api call . In fact ,that is the cleaner way compare to refresh token using in other flow . And of course , you can also use code flow ,but that need user login and handle token/refresh token in your client app

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that your harness should be prepared to request any token when getting an Unauthorized status code. What I do in test is to check the expiration datetime, if close enough I refresh or get a new token whatever applies to your Auth. Also when getting an unauthorized status code my code does a refresh once and keep a count.  If I get another unauthorized code then I return a false or throw an exception after I log the error on the second try. This works fine for me.